# Git - post-receive hook with git pull "Failed to find a valid git directory"

Tags: unix, git, hook

It's very weird but when setting a git repository and creating a post-receive hook with:

```
echo "--initializing hook--"
cd ~/websites/testing
echo "--prepare update--"
git pull
echo "--update completed--"
```

the hook runs indeed, but it never manage to run git pull properly:

```
6bfa32c..71c3d2a  master -> master
--initializing hook--
--prepare update--
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
Failed to find a valid git directory.
--update completed--
```

so I'm asking myself now, how it's possible to make the hook update the clone with post-receive?

in this case the user running the processes is the same, and its everything inside the user folder so I really don't understand...because if if I go manually into

```
cd ~/websites/testing
git pull
```

it works without any problem...

any help on that would be pretty much appreciated

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While the hook is running, `GIT_DIR` and (if the worktree was defined explicitly) `GIT_WORK_TREE` are set. That means your pull won't run with the second repository in the directory you changed to.

Try `git --git-dir ~/websites/testing/.git --work-tree ~/websites/testing pull`; or unset  git's repo-local environment with this:

```
unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
```

More info on these environment variables in [man 1 git](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Tobu, it really works, I will check out more information about it too. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

One thing I experienced was that using the `post-update` hook '--git-dir' worked great but git was still complaining about a missing working tree (despite using '--work-tree')

In short, this did not work:

`git --git-dir /path/to/websites/testing/.git --work-tree /path/to/websites/testing pull`

whereas this worked:

`cd /path/to/websites/testing

git --git-dir /path/to/websites/testing/.git pull`

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this work?

```
cd /home/smb/websites/testing
env -i git pull
```

**Edited**

Better still

```
cd /home/smb/websites/testing
unset GIT_DIR
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the full path instead of the ~?

```
cd /home/smb/websites/testing
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is probably invoked with `/bin/sh`, which doesn't understand `~`.  Try it with the full path to `~` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first recommended answer is right - when a hook is running GIT_DIR etc are set. However, if you want to be able to use the script in another repository then that method is flawed because it hard-codes resetting the GIT_DIR.
As they implied, the other way is to remove the variable by using env as follows:
env -i git reset --hard
Obviously what command you run there is up to you - it's just the 'env -i' bit that's the important bit.