# git pull in a hook not executing

Tags: git

I have a system setup like this:

http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

However no matter how I configure the shell environment (i.e. GIT_DIR and PWD) the git-pull command does NOT run when called by the hook.  Literally there is NO output whatsoever.

My post-update looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh    
/git/Lunch.git/lunch-receive > lunch.txt
```

and my lunch-receive script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
service myService stop
cd /usr/lunch
unset GIT_DIR
git reset --hard # necessary or the pull fails
git pull hub master # this line DOESN'T RUN grrrrr!
chmod u+x *.sh
chmod -R u+x bin
service myService start
```

Finally, lunch.txt (the output) looks like

```
HEAD is now at 5956c0b [old commit message]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar question here: [Git - post-receive hook with git pull "Failed to find a valid git directory"](https://serverfault.com/questions/107608/git-post-receive-hook-with-git-pull-failed-to-find-a-valid-git-directory).

The long and short of it is, you'll need to unset GIT_WORK_TREE; or to make sure it really takes, pass in the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` parameters to your git pull.

Andrew